# Correct type of a static image file imported with import statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, webpack, types

I set up a React Native project with `react-native init` and I am using flow. I imported a local image file in `App.js` via:

```
import placeImage from './src/assets/american.jpg';
```

Displaying the image works fine but I'm confused about the type of `placeImage`.

`typeof(placeImage)` strangely returns `number` and I found out that the value of `placeImage` is just `1`.

Why is that? Is there a way to import and use a static image with sane typing?

Comment: `require` or `import` statement of an image >> returns a number ...

Comment: @HendEl-Sahli that does not answer my question, you just repeated my question. 1. How come that placeImage is a number and <Image source{placeImage} /> renders fine to the screen?